# Parallelize tasks

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have 4 tasks to compare the font family and font style of two PDFs. If I perform these 4 tasks serially it takes a long time. If I run them in parallel the result text doesn't come out correct.

```
public void Compare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(firstpdffont_compare));
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(secondpdffont_compare));
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(firstpdf_fontstyle_compare));
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(secondpdf_fontstyle_compare));
    //----after this append function which is not in thread
    Appendresult();
}
```

How can I successfully parallelize these tasks?

Comment: Which method is the slow code in?

Comment: @patashu i think u know if i go for serial process it is slower. and if i go for thread like this text is missing.

Comment: The easiest way to start several tasks and wait for them all to finish is to use [`Parallel.Invoke()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.invoke.aspx), but I think you have problems within the parallel tasks themselves which is causing the problem. We can't diagnose that without seeing the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is most likely that you need to wait for the tasks to complete before calling `Appendresult()`; however, `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` queues the task but does not wait for it to complete, so you're calling `Appendresult()` prematurely.

You might use the [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) and the [Task.WaitAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695.aspx) method for this. It is much easier to coordinate than the thread pool approach:

```
var compareTasks = new Task[] {
    Task.Factory.StartNew(_ => firstpdffont_compare, null),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(_ => secondpdffont_compare, null),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(_ => firstpdf_fontstyle_compare, null),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(_ => secondpdf_fontstyle_compare, null) };

Task.WaitAll(compareTasks); // wait for all 4 tasks to complete
// Appendresult();
```